# Where to put routines in Django project?

Tags: python, django

I have rather vast implementation of functionality needed for processing specific type of data stored in my Django DB (7 interconnected files containing ~100 lines of code each). There's a facade method in one of those files that I call from related method in `views.py` so that there is no mess inside of views file.

For now I put everything inside a new folder in the same directory where `settings.py` `urls.py` and `wsgi.py` are, but now every time I'm calling `makemigrations` I receive a handful of unrelated information that has nothing to do with changes in data model.

What is the best place to store those routines?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Placing additional python files alongside your `settings.py` should not create migration errors in the normal case. Are you sure these files are causing the errors?

To you question:

1. If you will use those functions inside a single app, you could create a subdirectory inside that app, for example `utils`; it should be on the same level as the `migrations` and `templates` directories of the app.
2. However, if you will be using those functions inside many apps you could create a new app without models and migrations, lets call it `custom_utils`, in which you can place all your functions.